# How to get OS version/name on mobile, tablet or PC in Angular project

Tags: angular, operating-system, device, detection, info

I am using Angular 9 in my project and I need to get device information such as OS name and version ...etc

Now I am using ngx-device-detector but not working in android version like 8 and below or 10 and ios mobile to get os version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**angular-device-information**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-device-information) its work for me perfectly in **Android**, **iOS** and **Windows**

```
 console.log(deviceInformationService.isMobile());  // returns if the device is a mobile device (android / iPhone / windows-phone etc)
  console.log(deviceInformationService.isTablet());  // returns if the device is a tablet (tablet iPad etc)
  console.log(deviceInformationService.isDesktop()); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceType()); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().os);  // returns os name like Windows/Andtoid/iOS/Linux/Mac OS X etc
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().osVersion);  // returns os version like 10/8.1/7 ...etc
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browser);  // returns browser name like chrome/firefox ...etc
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browserVersion);  // returns browser version as number
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browserMajorVersion);  // returns full browser version as number
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().screen_resolution);  // returns screen size like 1390x860/640x800 ...etc
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().cookies);  // returns cookies enabled or no 
  console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().userAgent);  // returns userAgent
```

Comment: How I can get the name of my windows device from above?

Comment: just try deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().os